# django override request.build_absolute_uri

Tags: django

I have an EC2 site which has both elastic ip and domain name. Some people use the elastic ip to access the site and some use the domain name.

I use the request.build_absolute_uri() to construct links to pages generated in the site, however, I want it always to return the link with the domain name not with the ip.

Is there a way to override this or should I just implement something simuilar to build_absolute_uri?

Thanks

Comment: you should be handling this at the `nginx` or whatever reverse proxy server you use

Comment: I'm currently using single ec2 instance with the webserver installed. Is there a way to in the apache.conf? Thanks

Comment: There is lots of documentation online to do that. Yes

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll search for this.

Answer (score 0):

`request.build_abosolute_uri` relies on `request.get_host()`, so it takes domain name or ip from `request.META`.

You can rewrite the values in `request.META` in you middleware or somewhere, but I don't think it's a good solution. It's better to create a custom function that will build an absolute uri but with domain name as a parameter.